# CakePHP get affected rows of raw SQL statement

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an action in my CakePHP app which runs a simple update statement via a method in the model like so:

```
public function remove_nasties(){
    $query = 'UPDATE holdings 
    SET holdings.account_id = CONCAT(account_id, "n")
    WHERE holdings.nasty = 1 AND Right(holdings.account_id,1) != "n";';

    return $this->query($query);
}
```

The query runs fine but how do I get the number of affected rows? All that is returned is an empty array.

Comment: (please always supply the version of the framework you're using)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model Method: `getAffectedRows()`:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getaffectedrows

Answer (score -2):

There's a problem with getAffectedRow() if you use i18n

try use

```
$this->params['paging']
```

instead